# I am trying to add nivo slider on my page but it is conflicting with lightbox. Is there any way i can avoid this conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to add nivo slider on my page but it is conflicting with lightbox. It is giving object not supported '$' error.Is there any way I can avoid this conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to have jQuery relinquish control of the `$` variable.

After including jQuery, make a call to `jQuery.noConflict();` and then any time you want to use jQuery, do it using `jQuery` instead of `$` so:

```
$("div p").hide();
```

turns into:

```
jQuery("div p").hide();
```

The page I linked to above has more examples.

Comment: thanks..but please explain me how to use this in code, as i am new to jquery field..do i need to write it inside every <script> tag at last ?

Comment: check the linked page for example usage. you only need to write that once after including jquery.